# If, else if, statements : Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript

I just started doing Javascript, I keep getting a syntax error and haven't managed  to find out where it stems from. Here's a snippet of what I wrote:

```js
let num1 = 5;
let num2 = 8;
let num3 = 10;

if (num1 === num2) {
  console.log("the comparison shows");
} else if (num1 > num2 = true); {
  console.log("Number 1 is greater than number 2. The value for num 1 is " + num1);
} else(num2 > num1 = true); {
  console.log("Number 2 is greater and the value is " + num2);
```

Comment: `num1 > num2 =true` is an assignment, `num1 > num2` is not a proper identifier. Just remove `=true` from the expressions.

Comment: The error in the console tells you which line of the script is the source of that error -> `num1 > num2 =true`

Comment: And you probably don't want `;` after your conditionals.

Comment: I am confused why you would write `num1 > num2 = true` but not `num1 === num2 = true` - surely your reasoning would say to do that? Of course the actual solution is just `num1 > num2`

Comment: ... also, JS `else` doesn't have condition, `else (num2 > num1 = true)` needs to be `else if (...)`.

Comment: You don't have to think if num1 is greater than num2. JavaScript will think it for you when you write the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `;` after the else if and else block and no need to equate the expression to true inside the else-if/else statements. No need for the condition in else statement . If none of the above passes the control will go to the else only

```js
let num1 = 5;
let num2 = 8;
let num3 = 10;
if (num1 === num2) {
  console.log("the comparison shows");
} 
else if (num1 > num2) {
  console.log("Number 1 is greater than number 2. The value for num 1 is " + num1);
} 
else
  console.log("Number 2 is greater and the value is " + num2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Following are problems with your code:

1. You are using `;` at end of conditions which you shouldn't
2. You are putting a condition for `else`. `else` executes when previous `if` block is not executed.
3. `num1 > num2` returns `Boolean`. You need to compare them using `==` or `===` not Assignment operator `=`. You don't need to compare them to `true` because they are `Boolean`

```js
let num1 = 5;
let num2 = 8;
let num3 = 10;

if (num1 === num2){ 
  console.log("the comparison shows");
}
else if (num1 > num2 === true) {
  console.log("Number 1 is greater than number 2. The value for num 1 is " + num1);
} 
else {
  console.log("Number 2 is greater and the value is " + num2);
}
```